# OnComplete action for button in recyclerview only applied to first position

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a activity where it displays candidate on recyclerview to cardview. All is functioning correctly except the code below greyed the button for only the first position. I will attach the screenshot below.

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLd43.png)

it should be if only one field value is true on in all documents, all the button should be disabled. But as you can see, only the first button is disabled.

Here is my code:

```
db.collection("cancol").whereEqualTo(currentuser, true).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Button btncan= findViewById(R.id.btncandidate);
            Toast.makeText(NewVoteMainActivity.this, "You have already used your vote.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(null);
            int disabled = Color.parseColor("#c2c2c2");
            btncan.setBackgroundColor(disabled);
        }
    });
```

I also tried this but also gives the same result:

```
db.collection("cancol").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Toast.makeText(NewVoteMainActivity.this, "Retrieving Documents..." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    
                        if (document.getBoolean(currentuser) == true) {

                            Button btncan= findViewById(R.id.btncandidate);
                            Toast.makeText(NewVoteMainActivity.this, "You have already used your vote.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(null);
                            int disabled = Color.parseColor("#c2c2c2");
                            btncan.setBackgroundColor(disabled);

                        }
                    }
```

How do I make the code apply to every button?

Comment: I don't see any code here that deals with a RecyclerView.

Comment: Yeah, please post the RecyclerView adapter code. How you are populating the data.